# How to update data in gridview without manual refresh in asp.net?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview, sharepoint-2010

I have created a sharepoint webpart with a button control and gridview control. When I click on the button control, a new window with two textboxes name and city will come. When I enter some data and click ok, the data is to be added to gridview. I have used javascript to get this window.

**Issue:-** The actual operation is performing and the data is being added to gridview. However, I am not able to check this new added data in gridview until I manually refresh the page. As this is not an ideal application behavior, can some one suggest me how we can achieve this.

Any help will be greatly appreciated...Thank you!

Comment: yes please share code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A refresh is required to see the updated data.

If you want to get rid of the postback experience,  you should wrap the whole thing in a update panel.

To trigger the postback the asp.net-friendly way, have a button on the page; hide it via css. And through js code you can trigger the click of this button.

Edit (code):

[image]

In short this is what I am accomplishing. I have put the Refresh button visible. It can be wrapped in a UpdatePanel if required.

## WebForm1.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApp.PopupAdd.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>GridView Refresh Example</title>
    <script>
        function openPopup() {
            open('popup.aspx','_blank', 'height=300,width=200')
        }

        function refreshPage() {
            document.getElementById('btnRefresh').click();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>GridView refresh example</h2>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="btnRefresh" runat="server" Text="Refresh" OnClick="btnRefresh_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript:openPopup()" Text="Add" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="StudentName" HeaderText="StudentName" SortExpression="StudentName" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Students]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

## WebForm1.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApp.PopupAdd
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

## popup.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="popup.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApp.PopupAdd.popup" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script>
        function update() {
            window.opener.refreshPage();
            window.close();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

## popup.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApp.PopupAdd
{
    public partial class popup : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var sql = "insert into students (studentname) values (@name)";
            SqlConnection cxn = new SqlConnection();
            cxn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager
                .ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            var cmd = cxn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TextBox1.Text);
            cxn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cxn.Close();
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"update", "update()", true);
        }
    }
}
```

The table I used is the a simple students table with fields id, studentname.

My earlier suggestion was to hide the refresh button with css. (`style="visibility:hidden"`)

Comment: can't you update the gridview by doing a databind() when the operation takes place?

Comment: I think the OP is updating db via a popup page of some sort.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response and elaborate explanation. I was able to achieve my desired functionality using your approach also. However, I have used timer solution suggested by smirnov for now :)

Comment: Wow. A timer is great. But I'd still avoid it, since it will unnecessarily refresh that page. Hence instead of even hiding a button, I'd actually put a refresh button there.

Comment: great solution deostroll, working excellent..You have been great help throughout the issue. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Add the GridView and the Timer control inside an ASP.NET AJAX UpdatePanel as shown below

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
     <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="60000" ontick="Timer1_Tick">
     </asp:Timer>

      <asp:GridView ...> 
      </asp:GridView>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>


protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
     GridView1.DataBind(); 
}
```

Interval is the number of milliseconds, the default value is 60,000 (60 seconds).

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response and elaborate explanation. I was able to achieve my desired functionality using your approach...:)